# Cannot close a fabric panel with react correctly

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs, spfx

When I click on close on the fabric ui panel, the screen in the background remains grey , so it seems that it is still open

tried to change the onDissmed within the object, nothing seems to work.

```
<Panel
headerText='Case Approval'
type={PanelType.medium}
onRenderFooterContent={this._onRenderFooterContent} 
isOpen={this.state.showPanel}
onDismissed={ () => this._hidePanel}
onDismiss={this._hidePanel}>
<div>
<label>{myString.slice(7,myString.length)} is to be aprroved.</label>
</div>
</Panel>
private _onClosePanel = (): void => {
this.setState({ showPanel: false });
}
```

How can I completely dispose of the panel so that the users can use Sharepoint again without having the press the refresh button on the browser ?